# Find equation of ellipse

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

I have an ellipse with focal points at $(-2,0)$ and $(2,0)$ and one of the tops is at $(0,4)$. I need to determine an equation of ellipse in form like $ax^2 + by^2 - c = 0$ based on this information. I can't figure out how to do that. Could I have some advise on the problem? Thanks.

Found the solution thanks to @Tavish which is:

$4x^2 + 5y^2 - 80 = 0$

Comment: What do you know about the focal points ?

Comment: And what do you call a "top" ? The parameters given seem incoherent.

Comment: @YvesDaoust By top I meant one of the points having longest distance from the center. About focal points, my understanding is that the sum of their distance from center is equal to each other?

Comment: Any advise guys?

Comment: Mh, the distance between the foci is $4$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you describe is a standard ellipse. The foci are located at $(\pm ae,0)$ where $a$ is half the length of the major axis and $e$ is the eccentricity. So, $$ae =2$$ The distance from the origin to your *top* is $b$, half the length of the minor axis. $$b=4$$

Squaring the first equation and using the relation $e^2 =1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}$, $$ a^2 -b^2 =4 \implies a^2 =20 $$

The equation of the ellipse is $$\frac{x^2}{a^2} +\frac{y^2}{b^2} =1 \\ \frac{x^2}{20} +\frac{y^2}{16} =1 $$

Comment: What about the "normal form" of equation? I mean $ax^2 + by^2 - c$

Comment: @Mr.Engineer Multiply both sides by $80$.

Comment: from where does that $80$ come from?

Comment: @Mr.Engineer It’s the lcm of $20$ and $16$.